# Ruby: Sinatra and an infinite loop in one program

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have a program, which does something in an infinte loop (it a daemon).
This works fine.

Now I am planning to offer a webinterface for that daemon with the help of sintra. The sinatra code itself works fine too. But as soon as I have the loop and the sinatra code in one script, die sinatra code is **not** executed. There are no error messages on startup, but the local webservice isn't started.

Here the code stripped down to the basics:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require_relative 'lib/functions'

do_init_env # (some init steps, no influence on the startup of sinatra)

get '/' do
  erb :web
end

# infinity Loop
loop do
  if File.exists? somefile
    do_something
  end
  sleep 10
end
```

When disabling the loop, sinatra starts up fine:

```
ruby ./mydaemon.rb
[2013-02-26 12:57:24] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2013-02-26 12:57:24] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2013-02-06) [armv6l-linux-eabi]
== Sinatra/1.3.5 has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from WEBrick
[2013-02-26 12:57:24] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=13457 port=4567
^C
== Sinatra has ended his set (crowd applauds)
[2013-02-26 12:57:36] INFO  going to shutdown ...
[2013-02-26 12:57:36] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
```

When enabling the loop:

Silence, until interrupting the loop:

```
ruby ./mydaemon.rb

^C./mydaemon.rb:39:in `sleep': Interrupt
        from ./mydaemon.rb:39:in `block in <main>'
        from ./mydaemon.rb:33:in `loop'
        from ./mydaemon.rb:33:in `<main>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rack runs the script as-is when starting up. The "get" etc commands just stash information for Sinatra to respond to rack *later*. Any infinite loops will simply get started.

You could possibly solve this by adding threading, and starting the loop on a child thread. This might be worthwhile if the loop is doing something lightweight where you would gain performance by sharing a bit of memory with the web server. However, it is usually a coding headache to work with thread interactions.

You may be better off separating the web server and your long running loop into different scripts, running in their own processes, and have the loop emit readable data to e.g. a file or database, that the web server can pick up and serve.

Comment: I agree with your last statement, it's probably easiest to separate them out.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to run the Sinatra process as a daemon, maybe consider running it in its own process (and therefore with its own script). Consider e.g. using the daemons gem: http://daemons.rubyforge.org/

Comment: Daemons is a nice gem, I've also used [Servolux](https://github.com/TwP/servolux) and found it good.

Comment: I use daemons slready. The reason why I want to use the Webinterface in the same file as the daemon is, that i have some variables, they need to share ... but maybe i need to rethink my project setup :S